# rails 3: is there way to automatically create a hash from a string representation of a hash

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I have a string, which my app reads from a remote API source (Facebook graph), that looks like:

```
s = '{
     "id": "123456",
     "name": "App name",
     "link": "http://www.example.com",
     "location": {
       "street": "123 Main St",
       "city": "Anytown",
       "state": "XX"
      },
     "username": "platform"
    }'
```

Is there a simple method to create a hash from that string?

Comment: Are you sure this is the input? If you didn't have the last comma, you could have used JSON to parse.

Comment: you're right about the comma, which I just fixed, (I removed a lot of lines so it was shorter example). How would I use JSON to parse that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook Graph API returns a JSON document, that you can parse using `JSON.parse`.

```
s = '{
     "id": "123456",
     "name": "App name",
     "link": "http://www.example.com",
     "location": {
       "street": "123 Main St",
       "city": "Anytown",
       "state": "XX"
      },
     "username": "platform"
    }'
JSON.parse(s)
```

Output:

```
=> {"id"=>"123456", "name"=>"App name", "link"=>"http://www.example.com", "locat
ion"=>{"street"=>"123 Main St", "city"=>"Anytown", "state"=>"XX"}, "username"=>"
platform"}
```